# Why will my program work in an emulator but not a real device?

Tags: android

I recently wrote some code which is meant to find the location of a user via GPS. When I run the code in an emulator, the program runs fine. However, when I connect it to my phone, the program doesn't work and idles. Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package aw.com.testlocation;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&key=AIzaSyCxSv54uAgGv-pRULO_KQ6QWEciWmmanZo";
                JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            String address = response.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address");
                            textView.setText(address);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(request);
            }
        });
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        //textView.setText("Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                };
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                        }, 10);
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    configureButton();
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 20000, 0, locationListener);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                    case 10:
                        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                            configureButton();
                        return;
                }
            }

            private void configureButton() {
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 20000, 0, locationListener);
                    }
                });
            }

    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    }
```

Here is my activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="aw.com.testlocation.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="REQUEST LOCATION"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Location:"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="aw.com.testapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My logcat is too long to post :/
However, I do keep receiving the error: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

Any help is gladly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And you have an active internet connection on your device ?

Comment: "the program doesn't work and idles" -- please explain in detail what this means.

Comment: I do have internet connect to my device.

Comment: "the program doesn't work and idles" -- please explain in detail what this means. - The app comes up but doesn't do anything when I press the button.

Comment: Have you tried to fix what the error message says is the problem? `Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id'`... You have to update your strings.xml file with that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because on emulator you probably don't have even Google Play Services, clean AOSP. Google also provides emulator version with implemented GPS, but its optional, you probably dont use this (me too :) ). On this os-image version your maps API will not be even tried to execute due to no GPS-lib-on-device connection.

But also besides that read about implementing properly these files from logcat. check [HERE](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#processing_the_json_file). When you properly implement this part of import your app will work also on devices with Google Play Services.

Most of Google Play Services "parts" are running only on devices with Play Store, remeber

For more info show your Manifest and gradle files, so we cany say more about what you are importing, its clearly smth from Google (logcat!)

Comment: I have already tried implementing the google-services.json. Sadly, it hasn't worked for me :(. My manifest file is up now :D.

Comment: you've tried to implement  `google-services.json` file and it hasn't worked for you and now your app is crashing with `Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.` - why you are asking this question?! implement properly maps as in tutorial and everything will work. check that you are placing this json in proper folder and also check/show your gradle, you have to implement services in there